# GLSL - Only draw arond point / flashlight effect

Tags: libgdx, shaders, glsl, lwjgl, fragment-shader

I'm currently trying to achieve a sort of flashlight effect in GLSL. I only want to draw textures within a certain distance of a specified point (the mouse position, for example). Here's a quick example drawing of the effect I wish to achieve:

[image: Example]

I've successfully created a shader that checks the position from a certain point to the position of the fragment, and then discards the fragment if the distance is larger than the specified light radius. The frag shader looks like this:

```
#version 400

#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

in vec4 v_color;
in vec2 v_texCoords;
in vec2 v_position;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec2 u_mousePos;
uniform float u_lightRadius;

void main() {
    float distance = distance((v_position + 1.0) / 2.0, u_mousePosition);
    if(distance > u_lightRadius) {
        discard;
    }

    outColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
}
```

The problem with this shader is that the visible area isn't a circle, it's an elipse. This is obviously because the screen aspect ratio is not 1:1. I've tried multiplying the Y values of all of the position variables with a resolution uniform, but it still remains an elipse.

My other problem is that I wish to have smooth edges on my visible area. I've read up some on the subject and I see that you can use `mix` and/or `smoothstep` to achieve this, but I'm unsure on how to implement it.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the aspect ratio (and speed up the shader a bit):

```
void main() {
    vec2 diff = (v_position + 1.0) * 0.5 - u_mousePosition;

    diff.x *= u_aspect;  // e.g.: (16.0 / 9.0) for 16:9

    float distance = dot(diff, diff); // square of distance, saves a square-root

    if(distance > u_lightRadius_squared)) {
        discard;
    }

    outColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
}
```

To get a smooth edge remove the `if(...)discard` and add at the end:

```
outColor.a *= 1.0 - smoothstep(u_lightRadius_minus_one_pixel, u_lightRadius_plus_one_pixel, sqrt(distance));
```

For a less perfect but faster version:

```
outColor.a *= 1.0 - smoothstep(u_lightRadius_minus_one_pixel_squared, u_lightRadius_plus_one_pixel_squared, distance);
```

You can add back `if(outColor.a <= 0) discard;` at the very end to eliminate transparent pixels.

Comment: A disadvantage of `discard` is that it doesn't play very nice with antialiasing. Instead of discarding, set the `outColor` to transparent if the condition succeeds. Of course that was in the question already, just pointing out for future reference.

Comment: Works fine, except that it's not circular, it's still an oval. Any idea why?

Comment: Also, side question, could I use fwidth(distance) instead of the pixel size to get a smooth edge? I've seen people use it elsewhere. Or do I have the wrong idea of how to use it?

Comment: Nevermind the shape bit, I forgot to cast it to a float so width/height just became 1. I'd still like an answer to the other question though.

Comment: fwidth would work except on OpenGL ES 2.0, it's only available starting with OpenGL ES 3.0+ or any version of regular OpenGL.

Using a uniform makes that shader compatible with OpenGL ES 2.0

( https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/fwidth.xhtml )